# MIMO harmonic balance?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis

The standard harmonic balance approach is applicable if the system under consideration can be split into a linear part $G(s)$ and a static nonlinear function $u = f(e) = f(r - y)$.

In this scenario it is always assumed that $f(e)$ is a function that takes a scalar argument.

However, is harmonic balance still applicable if $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $G(s)$ is a transfer function matrix with $n$ outputs?

For example, let $G(s)$ have two outputs, $y_1$ and $y_2$ and $f$ be a 2D function.

Can harmonic balance be somehow used to analyse such a system?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can apply harmonic balance (in the time domain) to more general problems. Let's us consider the system

$$\ddot{x}+2\zeta\omega_0\dot{x}+\omega_0^2x=u_1+u_2$$
$$\ddot{y}+2\tilde{\zeta}\tilde{\omega}_0\dot{y}+\tilde{\omega}_0^2y=u_1-u_2$$
$$u_1 = \alpha x^3$$
$$u_2 = \beta y^3$$

Now, you would use an ansatz like $$x(t)=A\sin(\omega_1t+\phi_1)$$
$$y(t) = B\sin(\omega_2t+\phi_2)$$

to linearize the nonlinear terms $u_1$ and $u_2$ by harmonic balance.

Comment: I thought a bit about that suggestion but I wasn't really able to get the idea. Do you have some references/examples on how to do that exactly?